# Limiting the number of values per-key

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

Currently we have a dataflow process where we have a `GroupByKey` but the `DoPar` after the group-by is getting too many values per key and we wanted to know if there is a good solution for this. From what I can tell there is no way to set maximum number of values per-window.

Right now we are exploring 3 options:

1. Smaller Windows - we think we might still have issues with this since the events might come in clustered together in time.
2. Adding a random value in every key to partition the keys up - this is also not ideal because when we have less events coming in, we will have too few values per key. Also we can't adjust the number of partitions when the number of events goes up exponentially.
3. Some fancy triggering or using a combiner - probably the best solution, but not sure how to do this.

Is there a standard way or best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Each of the options you mentioned is possible, although which is ideal depends partly on what you're computing afterwards and whether you're running a batch pipeline on bounded data or a streaming pipeline on unbounded data.

1. You could create a custom `WindowFn` that limited the number of elements in each window. For example, you could assign each element to a window such as `(1, [startTime, endTime))`. Then you merge multiple windows together, adding their counts. You stop merging once the count is too high.
2. Randomly subdividing the keys is a good way to ensure partitioning and allow code to be better distributed across machines.
3. You could use a trigger such as "AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(500)" to output panes of ~500 elements. If the only problem was the size of the iterable into the DoFn this should help. This will also produce more/earlier outputs, which may or may not be desirable.
4. If the computation in the `ParDo` is associative and commutative, writing a `CombineFn` will yield to much less data being stored, and will improve the overall pipeline performance for both batch and streaming.

If you can describe your specific that may guide you towards one of these solutions. Otherwise, we'd suggest starting with the `CombineFn` if possible and seeing if you need to pursue other paths after that.